# Load balance 2 wireless adapters on 2 different computers (ie. w/NLB)

Tags: networking, nlb, windows-nlb

I have 2 physical servers running 2012R2.

Each box has its own wireless nic.

I also have 1 SSID to which both servers/WLANs connect to.

While trying to setup NLB, I noticed the Wireless NICs didn't show up.

- I was wondering why (ie. technically) it is not possible to enable
  NLB on wireless adapters (ie. in order to share the same IP Address).
- Is it because you can't enable promiscous mode on wi-fi adapters?
- Any hacks/workarounds/3rd party alternative solutions?

Thanks.